# Error handling with non existing filter

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, pivot-table

I've written some VBA code to create a PivotTable which should be filtered automatically. There a two possible filters: `0` and `1`. It is possible that both exist but it is also possible that only one of them exists.

I want Excel at first to set the filter on `0` and copy some rows to another table (that's what `Call b02_articleunit0` does). If that's done I want Excel to do the same thing with filter `1` but unfortunately it's not working. Even if both filters exist, only the first one (in this case `0`) will be handled. But it should also handle the second filter and save the workbook at the end with `Call SaveXLS` which is working fine if it can be executed.

Do you have any ideas how to optimize my code?:

```
Sub PivotTable()
[...]

Dim pf As PivotField
Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Abgleich_ME1_ME2")
'Remove existing filter
pf.ClearAllFilters

'Filter on 0
On Error GoTo fehler0:
pf.CurrentPage = "0"
Call b02_articleunit0
Exit Sub
fehler0: Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("D19").Value = "This filter isn't existing! (Filter 0)"
Resume Next

'Filter on 1
On Error GoTo fehler1:
pf.CurrentPage = "1"
Call b02_articleunit1
Exit Sub
fehler1: Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("D19").Value = "This filter isn't existing! (Filter 1)"
Resume Next

Call SaveXLS

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Because of a misunderstanding, I'll try to describe my problem better.

The Column `Abgleich_ME1_ME2` could contain some values like in the table below. The columns `1`, `2` and `3` describe three different cases which are possible.

```
1  |  2  |  3  
---------------
1  |  0  |  1  
1  |  0  |  0  
1  |  0  |  1  
1  |  0  |  1
```

*First case:* All values in the column `Abgleich_ME1_ME2` are `1`. The pivot table will be created with the filter as column `Abgleich_ME1_ME2`. Because this column contains only `1`, there isn't a filter `0`. So there would be an error if I execute vba code which tries to set the filter to this value. Anyway, in this case I want only the call `b02_articleunit1` to be executed. Otherwise my data would be wrong.

*Second case:* It's the same as the first case but only for `0`. At the end only the call `b02_articleunit0` should be executed.

*Third case:* Both calls should be executed because the filter contains both values.

Comment: Are `b02_articleunit0` and `Call b02_articleunit1` otherwise functioning correctly?  I.e., if you stripped out everything except the `'Filter on 0` section or everything except the `'Filter on 1` section, would they work for that case? If they do, then the solution @FreeMan posted should work.  If not, you'll have to post more code.

Comment: Yes, both behave as they should. But if I remove everything except the `Filter on 1` part and the column `Abgleich_ME1_ME2` contains only values like in case 2 in my example, then the `Filter on 1` part shouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
On Error GoTo fehler0:
pf.CurrentPage = "0"
Call b02_articleunit0
'-----------------remove this next line---------------------
Exit Sub
'-----------------------------------------------------------
fehler0: Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("D19").Value = "This filter isn't existing! (Filter 0)"
Resume Next
```

When your code returns from `b02_articleunit0`, then next thing it does is exit the subroutine.

Since you want to have different error messages in your error handler, try something like this:

```
On Error GoTo fehler:
pf.CurrentPage = "0"
Call b02_articleunit0

pf.CurrentPage = "1"
Call b02_articleunit1
Exit Sub

fehler0: 
  Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("D19").Value = "This filter isn't existing! (Filter " & pf.CurrentPage & ")"

Resume Next
```

That way you have one error handler, it's at the end of your code, and it dynamically displays the error based on your PivotField setting.

**Update**

Based on the example data you posted in OP, you really need to find what's in the column & execute your function calls based on that. Maybe something like this:

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim I as integer

For I = 1 to 3 'assuming they're the first 3 columns, adjust as necessary
  set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(i).find (What:=0, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  if not rng is nothing then
    pf.CurrentPage = "0"
    Call b02_articleunit0
  end if
  set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(i).find (What:=1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  if not rng is nothing then
    pf.CurrentPage = "1"
    Call b02_articleunit1
  end if
Next
set rng = Nothing
```

This will loop through each of the 3 columns, search each column for a `0` & execute `b02_articleunit0` if it finds one, then search that column for a `1` and execute `b02_articleunit1` if it finds one.

If that's not what you're after,I'm still very, very lost.

Comment: That's not working for me. If I'm doing it as you've suggested, excel will execute both calls. In my example `Abgleich_ME_ME2` contains only `1` but excel will execute also `b02_articleunit0` and won't call `SaveXLS` at the end.

Comment: "_excel will execute both calls_" Isn't that what you wanted?  Sorry, I missed the `SaveXLS` line, you'll have to put that in before the `Exit Sub`.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. Both calls should only be executed if **both filter exist** in the PivotTable. Otherwise there should only be the one executed which filter exists.

Comment: Maybe I'm lost on what you mean by "Both filters exist".

Comment: Let me try to explain it. The pivot table is build with raw date from another table sheet which content can change. The column `Abgleich_ME1_ME2` is a comparison between two units in different columns of the raw data. If the two units in one row match each other, then there will be a `1` in the `Abgleich_ME1_ME2` column. Otherwise a `0`. So both is possible but the column `Abgleich_ME1_ME2` could also contain only `0` or `1`.

Comment: Ah, you need to execute `b02_articleunit0` and `b02_articleunit1` if column `Ableich_Me1_ME1` contains _both_ 1s and 0s, but execute _neither_ if it contains _only_ 1s _or_ 0s.

Comment: That's not the way it should behave. I've edited my question with some examples.